# function with WriteFile- writing to serial port

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, serial-port

I want to include writeFile function of serial port wtiting to a fuctiona and call that function several time. I wrote following code. But function is returning false. I could not find any error.

```
bool WriteBuffer (char *lpBuf,DWORD dwToWrite){

//  DWORD dwBytesWritten;
//  DWORD dwToWrite;
printf("%s", lpBuf);

 if(!WriteFile(hSerial, lpBuf, sizeof(lpBuf) ,&dwBytesWritten, NULL))

        { 

        FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        GetLastError(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPWSTR)&lastError,
        1024,
        NULL);

    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    hSerial=NULL;
    printf("ERROR in WRITE FILE \n");
    return false;
//Handle Error Condition
}
printf("You wrote'%s'",lpBuf);


 return true;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where hSerial is created?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `sizeof(lpBuf)` to the `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` parameter. But `sizeof(lpBuf)` is simply the size of a pointer. You should be passing `dwToWrite` I presume.

If that doesn't solve your problem then the other cause of errors in `hSerial` not being valid.

Having gone to all the trouble of calling `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage`, it would have been helpful if you had told us what those functions returned.

Comment: But, why should passing sizeof(lpBuf) cause a failure? It should write either less bytes or more bytes (if dwToWrite is smaller than sizeof(lpBuf)). Incase of more bytes, it may lead to some "array out of bounds" read, but will it cause failure?

Comment: @Jay It could potentially cause failure if WriteFile tries to write beyond the end of the buffer and that can cause an AV. There's not much more that can be said give the code here. hSerial is the other possible failure point.

Comment: I am sorry. But, what's an AV?

Comment: @Jay Access Violation, aka segmentation fault, aka general protection fault.

Comment: Thats mean if the hSerial is not open, function will fail. I will check it too...

Comment: @Kumaa Please please tell us what happens when you call GetLastError?

Comment: Jay and David, Thank you for your replies. Error wan on hSerial.